# Titanium XHR cannot connect the server

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I' trying to let android app using titanium connect the localhost via xhr, here is the code:

```
    function e (){
    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onload = function()
    {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
     };
    xhr.onerror = function()
    {
        alert("Error");
    };
    xhr.open("GET","http://localhost/test.php");
    xhr.send();}
```

I get an error, and this appears in the process trace:

> I/TiHttpClient(  211): (TiHttpClient-1) [16,27717] Sending error
>   Connection to http://localhost refused

Answer (score 3):

the Android Emulator has its own network interface, so localhost is the emulator, not your host machine. You need to use the IP address 10.0.2.2 to access the machine that the emulator is running on.  See http://juristr.com/blog/2009/10/accessing-host-machine-from-your/

Answer (score 0):

Try to open with your IP. Like

```
 xhr.open("GET","http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/test.php");
```

(I've done this with Objective C not with Titanium. But you can give it try)

**EDIT**

Define Port number

```
xhr.open("GET","http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888/test.php");
```